# How to summarize and illustrate evidence based on several meta-analyses?

Tags: presentation, meta-analysis

I need to find a good way to summarize and illustrate the evidence of several meta-analyses (e.g. 20 papers). As far as I know, their conclusions are commonly made on two scales: effect size (does X has an effect on Y) and what quality evidence supports it. Therefore, would it be a good idea to show these papers on a single plot?
[image]

**Or are there any better ideas?**